# Is there a way to get all functions of a class with the decorator "@property"?

Tags: python, python-decorators

The only way I have come across is parsing through the class file. Is there a way to do this through the classes object itself?

Comment: `YourClass.__dict__` would be a good starting point.

Comment: @KlausD. Technically, you wouldn't be able to differentiate between "decorated" properties, and ones created "manually" by calling the property function. Unclear if OP cares, and which way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to list all the class attributes and check them against `property`:

```
properties = [n for n, p in YOUR_CLASS.__dict__.items() if type(p) == property]
```

You can also store `p` as well if you need a direct access to the getter/setter/deleter function.